# Работаю педагогом математики или учителем математики?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я работаю педагогом математики.

У нас в школе есть педагог математики.

Наша педагог математики очень злая.

Как-то не очень хорошо звучит словосочетание "педагог математики"! Его вообще можно употреблять? Или лучше использовать слово "учитель"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуется предлог "по":
*Я работаю педагогом по математике.*

Но лучше так, а то да, не очень звучит:
*Я работаю преподавателем математики.*

Comment: А почему требуется предлог "по" и почему "лучше так"? Ведь речь идет, если я правильно понимаю, о школе. Чаще всего в обычных школах работают обычные *учителя*.

Comment: У нас (не знаю, как у вас) "учитель" звучит не очень солидно. Но я не против, просто думаю, что "преподаватель" здесь звучит лучше. С предлогом явно лучше звучит.

Comment: А солидность-то тут причем?

Comment: Оказывает влияние на звучание.

Comment: Спасибо, oleedd, большое! Вот и в Нацкорпусе нет. Нет ни "педагог математики", ни "педагог химии". Просто я встретила это на официальном форуме одной московской школы. Как звучит - не понравилось. Там ещё много чего интересного и не совсем понятного для меня (в одном только посте)!

Comment: Я извиняюсь, Римма. Вы написали: "А солидность-то тут причем?" А разве не "ПРИ ЧЁМ"?

Comment: Встретил там "педагог вокального класса", оно звучит.

Comment: Да, здесь звучит...

Comment: Алёнушка, объяснение есть здесь. (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC) *Причём всё это? Дети-то причём, мы о них не говорим.*

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Позиция роли не играет. В вопросах пишется раздельно. А в БТС сделали реформу (поменяли на слитное). Это всё обсуждали, когда Sharon задавала вопрос.

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/37.htm

Comment: Не буду размахивать крылами. Раз порешали — пусть так и будет. За всем не уследишь, в особенности в ЕС.

Comment: Грамота, отвечая на вопросы о "причем / при чем", рекомендует ориентироваться  на **орфографический** словарь. А также пишет: "Что касается слитного написания в Большом толковом словаре – мы передадим Ваш вопрос главному редактору словаря С. А. Кузнецову".

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Главное — чтоб нос мой сильно не пострадал.